# Golang Why aren't these two strings equal?

Tags: go

I copied and pasted these two strings (one from a Google Doc and one from terminal) – what the heck is going on? And how can I clean them up so they are the same?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println([]byte("f6f77482e4394a21815b7090bc0185b4"))
    fmt.Println([]byte("f6f77482­e439­4a21­815b­7090bc0185b4"))
}
```

Returns:

```
[102 54 102 55 55 52 56 50 101 52 51 57 52 97 50 49 56 49 53 98 55 48 57 48 98 99 48 49 56 53 98 52]
[102 54 102 55 55 52 56 50 194 173 101 52 51 57 194 173 52 97 50 49 194 173 56 49 53 98 194 173 55 48 57 48 98 99 48 49 56 53 98 52]
```

Which are clearly two different byte arrays for the same string.

https://play.golang.org/p/_zd7tjqCZl

Comment: Copying the first one and pasting it multiple times duplicates the first string, and same with the second string. I think it has something to do with the encoding of the strings.. check this: https://play.golang.org/p/fSgO40Nz_-

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second one has a number of "soft hyphen" (U+00AD) characters between the visible characters, the first one appearing between "482" and "e4". A soft hyphen is a character that's invisible unless it happens to be at the location of a line-break, then it appears as a hyphen. Did you copy-paste the code from a word processor or some other program that might have applied special text formatting to it?

Comment: i did copy and paste actually from google docs preview mode. thanks for helping me untangle this mystery

Comment: @K2xL yeah, always be careful when copying code from apps that weren't meant for dealing with code, they can do all kinds of funny things to it :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the second one has 4 Unicode Soft Hyphens `0+00ad` which are not printable on the playground.

What you are actually doing is basically similar to...

```
fmt.Println([]byte("f6f77482e4394a21815b7090bc0185b4"))
fmt.Println([]byte("f6f77482­-e439­-4a21-­815b­-7090bc0185b4"))
```

This is what is looks like pasted into vim

[image: This is a screenshot in vim]